# how to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1) \cup \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis

how to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)\cup\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Do you know how to define a bijection between $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 1]$? Because if you don't, then that's a better place to start. And if you do, that's a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, I do know hot to define a bijection between (0,1) and (0,1]. Also, I do know how define one between (0,1) and $(0,1) \cup {1,2,3...k}$. I get stuck when there is N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick distinct $a_n\in (0,1)$ and set
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}n&x=a_n\text{, }n\text{ odd}\\
a_{n/2}&x=a_n\text{, }n\text{ even}\\
x&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: I took a time to understand. But that works fine. Thank you =)